# How does Bond's radio survive the EMP?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, no-time-to-die

In *No Time To Die*, Q gives Bond a special watch that emits an EMP (electro-magnetic pulse) that destroys electronics.

At one point, Bond uses the watch to kill a villain by making his electronic eye explode. Ignoring the fact that it seems to work more like a microwave than an EMP for a moment, the very next thing Bond does is talk to to Q on the radio. Given he just set off an EMP that caused the eye to explode, how come his radio is still working?

Answer (score 4):

When Q gives Bond the watch, he offers some caveat about the EMP only working on something like wired systems -- apparently it doesn't radiate a pulse, but induces an overwhelming current in whatever it's touching when it is triggered. I can't find a script with the exact phrasing, but it was distinct enough for me to wonder why Q was mentioning such a limitation.

Not that this makes sense, in physics terms, but presumably the pulse comes from the face of the watch and the wearer could be insulated from it. Of course, Bond is grappling with Cyclops when he triggers the watch, so he and his earpiece would no longer be insulated.

We can surmise Q might plan for this contingency and equip Bond with a hardened earpiece designed to resist the pulse put out by the watch Q had also developed.